# show value in the texbox using ajax - php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getvalues() {
            var selname = $("input[name='names']:text").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                data: {
                    "selname": selname
                },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (output) {
                    console.log(output);
                    $("#aic").val(output[0]);
                    $("#batchcode").val(output[1]);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="names" id="query" onblur="getvalues()" />
        <input type="text" name="aic" id="aic" />
        <textarea name="batchcode" id="batchcode" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['selname']))
{
    $response = array('0001', 'short info : john 29 years old - technician  '); // add return data to an array

    echo json_encode($response); // json encode that array

    exit;
}

?>
```

when I type something on  `input type="text" name="names"`
I get on input text `"aic" >>>  1;` but in the textarea I didn't get `"short info : john 29 years old - technician  "`,  please tell me where is the mistake!!

Comment: What does console.log show?

Answer (score 1):

Convert json to array

```
    var array = JSON.parse(output)
    $("#aic").val(array[0]);
    $("#batchcode").val(array[1]);
```

Comment: Should not be necessary

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function getvalues() {
            var selname = $("input[name='names']:text").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php",
                data: {
                    "selname": selname
                },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (output) {
var output = jQuery.parseJSON( output );
                    console.log(output);//use output.property
                    $("#aic").val(output[0]);
                    $("#batchcode").val(output[1]);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)